# Can I connect a gazebo light to a shed sub-panel or outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have a sub-panel in my garage and there is UF cable 12-2 running underground to my shed with a disconnect box, and the 12-2 wire is running to a GFI.  Within the shed, I have another 20 amp outlet, two ceiling lights on a single pole switch and two outside lights on their own switch.  I’m adding a gazebo on my deck and need to add a ceiling fan with a single pole switch and one outlet.   Can I run another UF 12-2 underground to my shed and tie the wires to the disconnect box or to the other 20 amp outlet?

Here is the diagram:
[image: diagram]

Comment: Your plan and descriptions are not entirely clear. I think that I understand what you want to do, but the exact layout is kind of important. How far away are these runs? You might need to increase the diameter of the wire and breaker size going from the garage to the shed in order to add a run from the shed to a gazebo. Or it might be easier to go from the garage to the gazebo.

Comment: First – I would like to thank you for your response.  I have added numerous outlets, recessed lighting etc. You are right, running the wire from the sub-panel is probably the easiest option (it’s only about 14 feet), but I’m not comfortable with going into the electrical panel to run wires – only to shut down the power.   If possible, can I run the UF 12-2 wire to the disconnect box or to the 20-amp outlet which is approximately 60 feet from the deck.

Comment: I can't tell if you are actually talking about a disconnect or not... to my knowledge you cannot make extra connections in a disconnect box, so why would you think that would be okay (or more comfortable than) going from the subpanel? Where would you attach the wires? How large is the breaker going to the disconnect? How large is the main breaker in the subpanel? How many small breakers do you have in the subpanel? Can you add pictures of the (open) subpanel and (open) disconnect box?

Comment: Where is the other 20 amp outlet, two ceiling lights on a single pole switch and two outside lights (on their own switch) comming from? The disconnect or the subpanel? Are they all on the same circuit, connected together in an outlet or switch box in the shed? Is everything in the shed comming from one breaker?

Comment: Is this the lay-out? [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rZJRP.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rZJRP.jpg)

Comment: @BenWelborn feel free to post pictures to the chat and copy the link to a comment here, rather than posting a non-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the garage panel is a subpanel and not a service entrance, you should be able to turn the entire subpanel's feeder off upstream -- I'd lock it out with a breaker-lock + padlock myself to avoid a shocking surprise from somebody else in the family.

With that done, running the gazebo circuit into the subpanel should not be an issue -- it's like running wires into a giant junction box in that you'll need to support and clamp them in the same way as you would a box. Once you have the wires in there with enough slack to make the connection -- simply screw the bare wire to the ground bar, the white wire to the neutral bar, and the black wire to the screw terminal on a spare 20A breaker, presuming you have one.  You'll also have to take the front cover (dead front) off and put it back on, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Once everything is hooked up, put back together, and ready to go, simply take the lock off the feeder breaker and turn it back on.